# ImportError: cannot import name 'set_random_seed' from 'tensorflow' (C:\Users\polon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Good day,

Here is the error. Can somebody help how can i solve it?

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-c29f17706012> in <module>
      7 import numpy as np
      8 import numpy.random as nr
----> 9 from tensorflow import set_random_seed
     10 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     11 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

ImportError: cannot import name 'set_random_seed' from 'tensorflow' (C:\Users\polon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py)
```

Looked for similar problems on Stack, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Are you using TensorFlow 2? https://github.com/IDSIA/sacred/issues/445

Comment: Yes, TF2. Seems the case for me, but is there solution on github? Only way is to set back tf version, right?

Comment: The github link contains the line: `tf.set_random_seed(seed)` has changed to `tf.random.set_seed(seed)` in TensorFlow 2. That would seem to be at the root of your import problem.

Comment: @DavidBuck Yes, right. Didnt work for me first time because i tried to import random from tf but it already works, no need to do this import.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In Tensoflow2 there is no need to perform

```
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
```

in order to run

```
set_random_seed(x)
```

(as it was in older version)

Only have to run

```
import tensorflow
tensorflow.random.set_seed(x)
```

Thanks to @David Buck

Answer (score 5):

I too faced same error but instead of
 `from tensorflow import set_random_seed`, I've used

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed()
```

And it worked I think that method is useful for version 1 and the above snippet is useful for version 2

Answer (score 3):

This code works for me:

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
from tensorflow import random
random.set_seed(1)
```

I got the same result of my neural network model every time.

Answer (score 3):

TensorFlow API has been updated from ***set_random_seed()*** to ***set_seed()***

You can use the following code :

```
from tensorflow.random import set_seed
```

Reference Link :

[TensorFlow Random Seed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed)

Answer (score 1):

you can also try the following import statement

```
from tensorflow.python.framework.random_seed import set_random_seed
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the random seed number.

You can try with this

```
import tensorflow as tf    
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
```